# Multilingual data bases for most common words and phrases used in games

Tags: databases

Games tend to have easy to understand instructions/menus/tutorials and so on, so I was wondering whether...

Are there multilingual data bases, built-in with the most common phrases used in games?

For instance Start, Resume, Play, Pause, Edit Profile, Awards, etc.

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not game specific, but see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792353/database-of-common-translated-phrases-for-localization

Basically the answers there boil down to:

- Use the Ubuntu translations tool/database: https://translations.launchpad.net/
- Check the Microsoft Language Portal: http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Default.aspx -- beware the license on this
- Use Google translate: http://translate.google.com/ (or [automate it](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/)) (folks seem to think it will do a reasonably good enough job for simple, common phrases).

All that said, I suspect there are some 'gamey' translations of some phrases that warrant a game-specific resource.  Hopefully someone else has those details.

Comment: certainly, "gamey" translations, shouldn't be too difficult, that could be the reason why there aren't any databases on the net to be used, I think I can build mine using resources like those you listed, and some multilingual games I've found, that have the kind of content I am planning to have